# Save first word a file in c

Tags: c

I have a problem with this part of my code, I'm trying to read the lines of a file and cut only the first word of each line and then save it in an array.

**Example:**

> two roads diverged in a yellow wood
>
> and sorry i could not travel both
>
> and be one traveler long i stood
>
> and looked down one as far as i could
>
> to where it bent in the undergrowth

and as a result I expect a vector like this: "two, and, and, and, to"

but I get this: "to, to, to, to, to".

**My code**

```
dictionary *load_word(int autor, dictionary *D_first)
{
  FILE *date;
  char line[LONG_MAX_LINE];
  char exeption[4] = " \n\t";
  char *word;
  int j=0;
  if (autor == 1)
  {
     if ((date = fopen("test.txt", "r")) == NULL)
     {
        perror("robert_frost.txt");

     }
     while (fgets(line, LONG_MAX_LINE, date ) != NULL)
     {   
        word = strtok(line, exeption); /*first word*/
        add_dictionary_first(D_first, j, word);
       j++;
     }

    fclose(date);
  }
  return D_first;  
}

void add_dictionary_first(dictionary *D, int cont, const char *value)
{
  expand_dictionary(&D, 1);
  D->Distribution[D->size-1]->cont = cont;
  D->Distribution[D->size-1]->value = value;
}
```

Comment: Maybe something is wrong with `add_dictionary_first`?

Comment: @uan J. Mart  The pointer word points to the same local array word = strtok(line, exeption);

Comment: Show us your `add_dictionary_first`

Comment: *The pointer word points to the same local array `word = strtok(line, exeption);`* yes but `strtok` also modifies the buffer, putting `\0` at the end of the first token. It depends how `add_dictionary_first` copies the word, if it just a pointer assignment then that's a problem, it needs to do a `strcpy`

Comment: already add the function.

Comment: `dictionary *load_word(blabalabal)` **what is** dictionary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lies within this line (as Vlad from Moscow posted in the comments):

```
D->Distribution[D->size-1]->value = value;
```

This is just pointer assignment. That's not wrong per se, but depending on the
context, it is not what you want.

```
while (fgets(line, LONG_MAX_LINE, date ) != NULL)
{   
    word = strtok(line, exeption); /*first word*/
    add_dictionary_first(D_first, j, word);
    ...
}
```

Here you call `add_dictionary_first` always with the same variable `line`. It is
an array but arrays decay into pointers when passing them as arguments to
functions. That means that all your `D->Distribution[D->size-1]->value` point to
the same location. The last line in your input file begins with `to` and that's why you get only
`to`.

You need to copy the string with `strcpy`.

> *man strcpy*
>
> ```
> #include <string.h>
>
> char *strcpy(char *dest, const char *src);
> ```
>
> The `strcpy()`  function  copies  the  string pointed to by `src`, including the terminating
>   null byte (`'\0'`), to the buffer pointed to by
>   `dest`. The strings may not overlap, and the destination string `dest` must be
>   large enough to receive the copy.

Because you haven't posted the structure I can only guess that `value` is
declared as `char*` (if it were `char[]` the compiler would have complained).

**Option 1**

```
D->Distribution[D->size-1]->value = malloc(strlen(value) + 1); // note the +1 here
if(D->Distribution[D->size-1]->value == NULL)
{
    // error handling
}
strcpy(D->Distribution[D->size-1]->value, value);
```

**Option 2**

If `strdup` is available in your system

```
D->Distribution[D->size-1]->value = strdup(value);
if(D->Distribution[D->size-1]->value == NULL)
{
    // error handling
}
```

In either case you would have to free the memory later.